# android studio "Use gradle wrapper" grayed out

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to import an eclipse project into Android studio.
In the [migration instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) it says "In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)"

The problem is that the ""Use gradle wrapper" is unselected and grayed out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. If I import the project anyway, I'm unable to build it using Gradle, even if I use the local installation. Did you solve it in any way?

Comment: No, I haven't. Import using gradle work only once for the first project for me, then it always fails...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1) Create a new simple project with Android Studio.

2) Find the **gradle** folder in the new project.

3) Use the export option in eclipse to create the build.gradle script. (Requires at least adt version 22.0)

4) Copy the **gradle** folder into the project you want to export to Android Studio.

5) Now try to import this project, u shall be able to select the wrapper check box.

This may resolve the problem you asked for, you can also set the Gradle home path and use the other option just fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: too old! This shoudnt be happening with newer versions of Android Studio AFAIK!

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue with a project that I had already previously built using Android Studio.  It turned out that selecting the project appended a `/gradle` to the path of the directory when searching for a gradle wrapper.  Removing the `/gradle` allowed me to select the option to use the default gradle wrapper.

Comment: This worked for me also, to clarify, the /gradle needs to be removed from the top field on that same page.

Comment: this answer was useful to me because it helped me realize that the project I was working on had originally been written using Android Studio, not regular IntelliJ IDEA. Reimporting the project into Android Studio solved my issues.

Answer (score 17):

For those **intellij + Gradle** users, that arrive here via Google...

I had the same "greyed out" issue, on osx, **NOT** on an Android project though.

To resolve, I had to...

Install gradle. (If not already installed)

(if you use Homebrew)

```
`> brew install gradle `
```

In the terminal, remove your gradle/wrapper folder.

Run the **gradle** wrapper task (this will download/create the wrapper)

```
> gradle wrapper
```

Attempt to re-import the project in **intellij**

Comment: No need of re-importing. The **Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)** option is now enabled. Just select it together with auto-import and the project is sorted.

Answer (score 5):

I had an existing project with this problem. I already had gradle on my system, so what I did to fix it was remove everything from my build.gradle except:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

If you don't have a build.gradle, create one. Then run `gradle wrapper`. This will download the wrapper. Then put the original (Android-ish) contents of your build.gradle back, and go to your Project Settings in IntelliJ/ADT. You should be able to choose the `Use gradle wrapper` option now

Comment: I did this with gradleVersion 2.0

Comment: it worked for me, but only after i deleted the gradle folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simpliest sollution which works for both AndroidStudion and Intellij Idea

1. Go to Preferences -> Build, Execution.. -> Build Tools -> Gradle
   [image]
2. Check "Use gradle wrapper task configuration"
3. Click apply (gradle wrapper will be downloaded, `gradlew`, `gradle.bat` files will be added to your project)
4. Check "Use default gradle wraper"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the only way I found to fix it was by deleting my Eclipse and SDK directories, deleting the settings/preferences, as well as my Android Studio settings/preferences.  It isn't the most elegant solution, but I was able to get it to work by doing this.

My suspicion is that something wasn't happening right during Export, because it was the last variable I changed after already attempting a reinstall of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else said, you need to first create a new project with android studio, and use the gradle file found in that project and paste it into the project which you want to import.